# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Marker>' of 'function result' Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing such an error, what should I do?

Since I could not find the source of the error, I am sharing the necessary code pages below, and I am facing a new error, https://prnt.sc/1s604iu.

......................................................................

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGLiz.png)

-Main-

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/blocs/application_bloc.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/models/place.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/praying_Screen/praying_ScreenPage.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/qiblah/qiblah_Screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class mosque_App extends StatefulWidget {
  const mosque_App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _mosque_AppState createState() => _mosque_AppState();
}

class _mosque_AppState extends State<mosque_App> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();
  late StreamSubscription locationSubscription;
  late StreamSubscription boundsSubscription;
  final _locationController = TextEditingController();

  Future<Applicationbloc?> verileriCagir()async{
    final applicationBloc= await Provider.of<Applicationbloc>(context,listen: false);
  }
  Future<dynamic?> callBounds()async{
    final applicationBloc= await Provider.of<Applicationbloc>(context,listen: false);
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
     var applicationBloc;
     verileriCagir().whenComplete((){
       locationSubscription= applicationBloc.selectedLocation.stream.listen((place) {
         if(place!=null){
           _goToPlace(place);
         }else{
           _locationController.text = "";
         }
       }
       );
     });
     boundsSubscription = applicationBloc.bounds.stream.listen((bounds) async{
       final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
       controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50.0));
     });

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    final applicationBloc= Provider.of<Applicationbloc>(context,listen: false);
    applicationBloc.dispose();
    _locationController.dispose();
    boundsSubscription.cancel();
    locationSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final applicationBloc= Provider.of<Applicationbloc>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body:(applicationBloc.currentLocation == null)
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
          :Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children:<Widget> [
            TextField(
              decoration:InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Konum Ara', //Search Location
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
              onChanged: (value)=>applicationBloc.searchPlaces(value),
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 500.0,
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                          applicationBloc.currentLocation!.latitude,
                          applicationBloc.currentLocation!.longitude),
                      zoom: 14,
                    ),
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      _mapController.complete(controller);
                    },
                    markers: Set<Marker>.of(applicationBloc.markers!),
                  ),
            ),



                if(applicationBloc.searchResults != null && applicationBloc.searchResults!.length != 0)
                  Container(
                    height: 300.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.6),
                        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.darken
                    ),
                  ),
                if(applicationBloc.searchResults!= null)
                Container(
                  height: 300.0,
                  child: ListView.builder( itemCount: applicationBloc.searchResults!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return ListTile(
                        title:Text(applicationBloc.searchResults![index].description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        onTap: (){
                          applicationBloc.setSelectedLocation(
                              applicationBloc.searchResults![index].placeID
                          );
                        },
                      );

                    },
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),

            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Wrap(
                  spacing: 8.0,
                  children: [
                    FilterChip(label: Text('En Yakın Camiyi Bul'),
                        onSelected: (value)=>applicationBloc.togglePlaceType('mosque', value),
                      selected: applicationBloc.placeType == 'mosque',
                      selectedColor: Colors.blue,

                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),










      bottomNavigationBar:Container(
        decoration:BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            top: Radius.circular(36.0),
          ),
        ),

        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children:<Widget> [
            IconButton(
              icon:Image.asset('assets/main_screen/icons/prayer_icon.png'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>PrayPage()));
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon:Image.asset('assets/main_screen/icons/quran_icon.png'),
              onPressed: (){},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon:Image.asset('assets/main_screen/icons/calendar_icon.png'),
              onPressed: (){},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon:Image.asset('assets/main_screen/icons/mosque_icon.png'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>mosque_App()));
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon:Image.asset('assets/main_screen/icons/compass_icon.png'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> QiblahCompass()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),

      ) ,
    );




  }
  Future<void> _goToPlace(Place place)async{
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(
            place.geometry.location.lat,
            place.geometry.location.lng),
        zoom: 14.0),

    )

    );
  }

}
```

-Marker Service-

```
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/models/place.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MarkerService{
  LatLngBounds? bounds(Set<Marker>? markers){
    if(markers == null || markers.isEmpty) return null;
    return createBounds(markers.map((m) => m.position).toList());
  }
  LatLngBounds createBounds(List<LatLng> positions) {
    final southwestLat = positions.map((p) => p.latitude).reduce((value, element) => value < element ? value : element); // smallest
    final southwestLon = positions.map((p) => p.longitude).reduce((value, element) => value < element ? value : element);
    final northeastLat = positions.map((p) => p.latitude).reduce((value, element) => value > element ? value : element); // biggest
    final northeastLon = positions.map((p) => p.longitude).reduce((value, element) => value > element ? value : element);
    return LatLngBounds(
        southwest: LatLng(southwestLat, southwestLon),
        northeast: LatLng(northeastLat, northeastLon)
    );
  }

  Marker? createMarkerFromPlace(Place place,bool center){
    var markerId= place.name;
    if (center) markerId = 'center';
    return Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(markerId),
        draggable: false,
        visible: (center) ? false : true,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: place.name, snippet: place.vicinity),
        position: LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat,
            place.geometry.location.lng)
    );
  }
}
```

-ApplicationBloc-

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/models/geometry.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/models/location.dart' ;
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/models/place.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/models/place_search.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/services/geolocator_service.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/services/marker_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:final_prayer/maps_with_mosque/services/places_service.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Applicationbloc with ChangeNotifier{

  final geoLocatorService= GeolocatorService();
  final placesService = PlacesService();
  final markerService = MarkerService();

  //Variables-Verilerim//
  Position? currentLocation;
  List<PlaceSearch>? searchResults;
  StreamController<Place> selectedLocation= StreamController<Place>.broadcast();
  StreamController<LatLngBounds> bounds = StreamController<LatLngBounds>.broadcast();
  Place? selectedLocationStatic;
  String? placeType;
  late List<Marker>? markers;

  Applicationbloc(){
    setCurrentLocation();
  }

  setCurrentLocation()async{
    currentLocation  = await geoLocatorService.getCurrentLocation();
    selectedLocationStatic=Place(name:'',geometry: Geometry(location:Location(lat:currentLocation!.latitude,lng: currentLocation!.longitude)), vicinity: '');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  searchPlaces(String searchTerm) async {

   searchResults = (await placesService.getAutocomplate(searchTerm)).cast<PlaceSearch>();
   notifyListeners();
  }

  setSelectedLocation(String placeId) async {
    var sLocation = await placesService.getPlace(placeId);
    selectedLocation.add(sLocation);
    selectedLocationStatic = sLocation;
    searchResults = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  clearSelectedLocation() {
    selectedLocationStatic = null;
    searchResults = null;
    placeType = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  togglePlaceType(String value,bool selected)async{
    if(selected){
      placeType=value;
    }
    else{
      placeType=null;
    }
    if(placeType != null){
      var places = await placesService.getPlaces(
        selectedLocationStatic!.geometry.location.lat,
        selectedLocationStatic!.geometry.location.lng,
        placeType!
      );
      markers= [];
      if (places.length > 0) {
        var newMarker = markerService.createMarkerFromPlace(places[0],false);
        markers!.add(newMarker!);
      }

      var locationMarker = markerService.createMarkerFromPlace(selectedLocationStatic!,true);
      markers!.add(locationMarker!);

      var _bounds = markerService.bounds(Set<Marker>.of(markers!));
      bounds.add(_bounds!);

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    selectedLocation.close();
    bounds.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `!` in consume list Markets. If you want to use `!` operator that variable must specify with null-check operator `?`.

i.e `late List<Marker>? markers`

Comment: Now I am facing an error like this => https://prnt.sc/1s5tgd4

Comment: Verify before access markers, it is initialized with values.

Comment: If you have time, if I give you my instagram, is it okay if we can contact you there? Because different problems are starting to appear ?

Comment: Share code snippet where do you init and consume will be better

Comment: Can you check again, I shared my codes again with a different error ?